# Weird issue with UIBarButtonItem custom background image

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uikit

I'm trying to customize the back button in iOS 5. This is the background image I want to use:

[image: background image]

It's 23 x 30 points.

My code to customize is:

```
UIImage *buttonBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-backbutton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 11, 0, 11) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]; 
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Geri" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[backButton setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBackground forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; 
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

This should do the trick, width of the image is 23 points and I'm setting right-left offsets by 11 points. But this is the result ("Geri" means "Back" in Turkish):

[image: back button]

What I don't understand is the size difference at the end. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### What's wrong with your code ?

Your `UIEdgeInsets` are incorrect for the image you are using, you're telling the UI to start stretching the image too soon. You should change the left value of your `UIEdgeInsets` to start the stretching a few more points to the right.

### What are edge insets ?

I noticed you commented on another answer you didn't understand how the edge insets work. So I drew this up for you.

[image]

The black lines represent the borders of your image. The orange lines represent the zone in which you want your image to become stretchable. Note the left cap appears when the button's rounded part has ended. The right cap appears just before the rounded corners of the right edge.

You can represent this to the UIKit by using `UIEdgeInsets`.

`UIEdgeInsets` is defined as follows ([see documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html)):

```
typedef struct {
    CGFloat top, left, bottom, right;
} UIEdgeInsets;
```

### Solution

In your case I downloaded the button you're trying to use, I found that the left cap should start at 14 pixels. The right cap should be at 18 pixels (5 pixels from the right edge).

So you should be using the following edge inset to correctly make your image resizable:

```
UIEdgeInsets correctInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 14.0, 0.0, 5.0);
```

### Compatibility (iOS 5 & 6)

Also please be aware that the resizing method from `UIImage` that you are using is only available from iOS 6:

```
-resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:
```

You should use this method instead to get this working okay in iOS 5:

```
-resizableImageWithCapInsets:
```

See [UIImage documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
 NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    IosVersion = [ver floatValue];

    UIButton * backButton ;
    backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 23, 19)];
    if(IosVersion >= 5.0)

        [backButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-backbutton"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 15.0f, 0.0f, 15.0f)]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    else

        [backButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-backbutton"]stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:15]forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [backButton.titleLabel setText:@"Geri"];
    [backButton setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 19)];

    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToHome) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *HomeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: backButton];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:HomeButton];
```

Comment: Actually `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 7)` did the trick, but I don't understand why. So you suggest to use `initWithCustomView`?

Comment: @newth the code here is creating a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view, it isn't using the `UIAppearance` protocol to customise native components. `UIAppearance` is only available from iOS 5 onwards so this solution works on earlier versions of iOS also. Which to be honest in this day is not that helpful anymore. You should be using the `UIAppearance` protocol for what you are doing. See my answer.